# New Project in Visual Studio 2017 creates empty solution

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, razor-pages

I'm following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-2.1) but when I get to the "The Visual Studio template creates a starter project" stage, the solution is empty (contains 0 projects).  Everything else looks fine until that stage.

What's happening?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by moving

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\`

above/up

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\dotnet\
```

in my path environment variable.